# How should lay buddhists respond to amoral people?

Tags: modern-world

How should lay buddhists respond to amoral people, people who keep generating bad karma for themselves but don't believe they've done anything wrong at all, especially if they have the power to get away with it materially speaking?

Comment: Treat them with kindness and according to Buddhsit values and ethics. If it doesn't work just leave them be - be mindful and focus on your own actions and life. Upvoted your question because I think it's good now.

Comment: I agree @LunarBastion

Comment: an ethic of quietism and restraint. it definitely sounds buddhist @LunarBastion

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, this does not answer your question, nevertheless, it is an **appropriate response** to the sort of situation you describe:

"Of course, there will be those who are misbehaving and refuse to change their ways, and there’s nothing—at least for the moment—you can do about it. That’s why equanimity is a necessary part of brahmavihāra practice. You reflect that beings are free to choose their actions, and you’re in no position to guarantee that everyone will choose to be skillful. Not even the Buddha could do that. So to keep your focus on training your own mind, you have to develop equanimity in cases where other people are beyond your ability to influence in a skillful direction."

That's from a section on "The Brahmavihāras" in [Undaunted](https://www.dhammatalks.org/books/Undaunted/Section0010.html#sigil_toc_id_8).

Life is choices, we have to choose where to direct our efforts effectively, skillfully. Sometimes that means abandoning those cases where we can't make a difference, or it's not worth our time and effort to try. That's not always easy to do, but the brahmavihāras can be very helpful in righting our emotional imbalances. Please have a look, for your own sake.

Comment: this is a really great answer, thanks. maybe they're amoral, maybe they're solipsists, maybe i'm just crazy. who knows! i won't deliberately make them unhappy, anyway

Comment: i could be more compassionate, i know that, that, it is a much more beneficent state of mind than ill will, even ill will you would never act on. i'll focus on equanimity for that, thanks